# Tsconfig outDir setting output in root directory

Tags: typescript

what do I miss in tsconfig setting? if I just want to output file in the root directory.

if I set

```
"rootDir":"src" 
"outDir":"build",
```

or

```
"rootDir":"src" 
"outDir":"",  -> got what I want, produce jsfile in root directory
```

both work, but when I set

```
"rootDir":"src" 
"outDir":"./"
```

nothing happens, why? can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must be missing the `"baseUrl": "./"` setting in the compilerOptions. Without it, the relative path in outDir won't be working.